# Hook module and Drop table

Tags: 7, hooks, database

I would know if it's possible to drop a database table created by a module.
I could see the hook "uninstall" and "disabled" but nothing works.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could sound a stupid question, but have you enabled your module?
Have you launched the uninstall procedure?

Comment: Hum, yes I have. I have enabled my module and I disabled. But the table doesn't drop

Comment: Disable does *not* uninstall. You need to go the the uninstall tab and uninstall your module there. Also, show your code.

Comment: @Berdir It seems the OP is asking about a third-party module. What you report about disabled modules is correct, indeed.